# Matlab Function block with Design Verifier

Tags: matlab, simulink

For example, I have a Matlab function block in my simulink model that is something like this:

```
function define_tests(row rowValues)
    for i=1:length(rowValues)
        sldv.test(row == rowValues(i));
```

The design verifier does not generate tests for each time I call `sldv.test`. It generates just one test for the last time it calls it.

Any thoughts for a possible solution to generate `length(rowValues)` tests? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [help page for sldv.test](http://www.mathworks.com/help/sldv/ref/sldv.test.html), it says

> This function has no output and no impact on its parenting function

It's not explicitly stated, but I'm assuming that `sldv.test` isn't necessarily "executed" or "called" in your function, per se, but rather is just acting as a way of denoting desired behavior for use by SLDV when it analyzes your function.  I gather that `sldv.test` isn't intended to be intermixed with control flow in your function, because SLDV isn't actually executing this control flow.

Also, consider the fact that if you were adding new control logic (such as for loops or if statements) to your function **exclusively** for the purpose of specifying how `sldv.test` is defined, then this would unintentionally add extraneous coverage objectives as well (for example, your for loop will have Decision coverage objectives associated with it).  (Not sure if that's relevant to your situation, but figured I'd throw that out there just in case)

I think that your best bet would be to avoid using `sldv.test` in a for loop and try to vectorize the test expression.  Using your example, that would look like this:

```
function define_tests(row, rowValues)
    sldv.test(all(row == rowValues));
```

This should have the desired behavior of specifying that all of the elements of *rowValues* equal *row*.

Here's a link to more info regarding [vectorization in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html).